# Get back URL from a file

Tags: linux, wget

Assume that i have downloaded a file in GNU/Linux using wget, the history in the terminal is cleared and i need to get back the URL from which i had downloaded the file.
How do i go about? Something like a reserve lookup file==>URL.

Answer (score 1):

You mean the (assuming bash) *.bash_history* file is cleared.

Then you are out of luck. You can't restore the url as wget doesn't have something like a history file or something like that (unless you used the `-o` or `-a` option yourself).

Comment: Yes *.bash_history* file is cleared. Let alone wget, is there any other app which can get the url given a file as an input.
{I had come across once such but don't remember it as of now, indeed bad luck} Is there any way out like : **file ==> (script) ==> URL**